# Why is calling ReadConsole in a loop corrupting the stack?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stack-corruption

I've disabled line input with the following code:

```
DWORD dwConsoleMode;
GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, &dwConsoleMode);
dwConsoleMode ^= ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;
SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, dwConsoleMode);
```

Then I am calling ReadConsole in a loop...in a loop:

```
wchar_t cBuf;

while (1) {
    /* Display Options */

    do {
        ReadConsole(hStdIn, &cBuf, 1, &dwNumRead, NULL);
    } while (!iswdigit(cBuf));

    putwchar(cBuf);

    if (cBuf == L'0') break;
}
```

If I run the program and press 0 right away, it exists cleanly.
But if I press a bunch of keys, then press 0, when the program exists it crashes with:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cBuf' was corrupted.

Why is this causing the stack to become corrupt? The code is simple, so I can't figure out what is wrong.

Little program that I can reproduce the problem with:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    DWORD dwNumRead;
    wchar_t cBuf;

    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    DWORD dwConsoleMode;
    GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, &dwConsoleMode);
    dwConsoleMode ^= ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;
    SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, dwConsoleMode);

    while (true)
    {
        wprintf(L"\nEnter option: ");

        do {
            ReadConsoleW(hStdIn, &cBuf, 1, &dwNumRead, NULL);
        } while (!iswdigit(cBuf));

        putwchar(cBuf);

        if (cBuf == L'0') break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You have to kind of mash your keyboard after you run it, then press 0, and it crashes with the stack corruption.

I also can't reproduce the problem every time, it takes a few tries.
I was running it under Visual Studio 2010, after creating a new empty console project and adding a file with that code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Could you please post a small but complete program exhibiting the issue?

Comment: I would suggest checking the return value of `ReadConsoleW` and examining `GetLastError` when needed. Otherwise, I haven't a clue!

Comment: Checked the return value of `ReadConsoleW`, but each time the return value was nonzero, so no errors. Also when it crashes with the stack corruption, the debugger is at the end of the program.

Comment: Wow. Nice catch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug in Windows.  Here is a slightly simpler program that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    DWORD dwNumRead;
    wchar_t cBuf[2];

    cBuf[0] = cBuf[1] = 65535;

    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, 0);

    while (true)
    {
        _ASSERT(ReadConsoleW(hStdIn, &cBuf[0], 1, &dwNumRead, NULL));
        _ASSERT(dwNumRead == 1);
        _ASSERT(cBuf[1] == 65535);
        Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

The sleep makes it a bit easier to trigger the issue, which occurs whenever more than one character is waiting at the time you call [ReadConsoleW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Looking at the content of `cBuf[1]` at the time the relevant assertion fails, it appears that ReadConsoleW is writing one extra byte at the end of the buffer.

The workaround is straightforward: make sure your buffer has at least one extra byte.  In your case, use the first character of a two-character array.

Comment: Interesting. Just curious, how come if I remove the Sleep function, I can't get it to trigger a break point? What does having it sleep for 5 seconds accomplish?

Comment: Without the sleep, you're unlikely to be able to hit keys quickly enough to get more than one read at a time, although using cut-and-paste might still work.  (Your original code was a bit slower to loop because of the putwchar and wprintf so a sleep wasn't essential.)